# How to correctly add Polyfills to SystemJS Angular 4 application

Tags: angular, systemjs, polyfills, angular2-aot, browser-support

I'm using SystemJS in development mode and AOT for production (not the best approach but that's what we started the application with an year ago). Everything was going okay when we were just testing on Chrome/Edge until we checked the site on IE/Firefox/Safari and found out its all broken. Nothing appears when checked in those browsers.

I searched a little and found that it might need some polyfills for different browsers support. In my SystemJS development environment, I have

```
<!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
<script src="~/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="~/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="~/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="/systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
System.import('app').catch(function (err) {
    console.error(err);
});
</script>
```

In my tsconfig.json, I have

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "app/aotfactories"
  ]
}
```

In my package.json dependencies, I have (dependencies related to configurations)

```
"core-js": "^2.5.1",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
"rxjs": "^5.4.3",
"systemjs": "^0.20.19",
"typescript": "^2.5.2",
"zone.js": "^0.8.14",
```

The line `/core-js/client/shim.min.js` I believed will serve my purpose but when checked out on IE/Firefox/Safari it still didn't had any impacts. I'm coming from the SystemJS background and not have much know how on webpack/cli based solutions.

My published vendor packages have the same `/core-js/client/shim.min.js` included but they don't work either with AOT.

Comment: if you didn't have the last in your app it wouldn't work even for Chrome, so I guess you already have them somehow imported

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com Didn't have the last what? Its working correctly in chrome and edge but not in others `https://carbid.co.il/`

Comment: the last 3 dependencies

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com They are coming from `node_modules`, its working okay in chrome and edge but doesn't load angular on firefox or ie

Answer (score 0):

Way late but if anyone finds this, I think the problem is you need a promise polyfill.

system-polyfills.js ships with systemjs and I'm planning to do something like this to load it:
if (window.Promise === undefined)
  // Load system-polyfills.js

...Question now is about loading, I think I'll just append a new script element to the body or something and see how that works...